# how do I turn off tap-to-click for logitech k400r wireless keyboard with touchpad?

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, touchpad, logitech, tap-to-click

I'm running kubuntu 12.04 i386 on lenovo thinkcenter.

There are no options for the touchpad under "Input Devices".

Is there anyway to turn off tap-to-click by editing some text file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Am not sure but I think that FN plus left click turns off tap to click.

Comment: thank you... that worked perfectly.  Is there any guide for this keyboard or even a GUI utility for keybindings?

Comment: yes. blue fn key and left click using the wireless keyboard touchpad button does the trick. This is an OS independent method so no need for installing wireless keyboard software.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wanted to enable(!) tap-to-click. it just works :)!

Comment: im trying hard to figure this out. Which OS are you using? FNCT and left lick isnt working

Comment: @KalamalkaKid: fn+left-click is the official way to do it, according to Logitech. I just did it on my K400 Plus and it works as expected. The normal way to do it, using System settings, does not work. Makes me think it's built-in to the keyboard rather than an OS thing.

Comment: Shitty garbage secret hotkey I never wanted, what is the point of having a "Tap to click" option in setpoint if I can unknowingly override it with this. Setpoint fucking sucks

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the same problem. No touchpad settings in systemsettings. But I don't remember how I fixed it :(

But I know that you can configure tapping with **synaptiks**.

Just start a terminal and type synaptiks or alt-f2 synaptiks.

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel > Change Mouse Settings > Hardware choose the right Mouse driver (for me it was called HID-Compliant Mouse) > Properties > Change Settings > Driver > Disable

Hope it works!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While we like seeing users, old and new, trying to help out other users with their problems, this seems a little excessive, disabling the entire driver. @13east only wanted to turn off tap-to-click while they were trying to edit a text file. Thanks for trying to help though!

Answer (score 0):

Now in 2020, the [Solaar application](https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/) handles these functions for many Logitech keyboards including the K400. It should be in most distros, and the *solaar* package is in Ubuntu's default repositories in 16.04 and later.

Comment: Solaar couldn't configure my K400R on Ubuntu 20.